# Docker: Drive has not been shared

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

When "dockerizing" an **ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC** application I got the following outcome:

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\admin\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "D:\xxx\yyy\Spikes\DockerizedWebApp1\DockerizedWebApp1:/app" -v "D:\xxx\yyy\Spikes\DockerizedWebApp1:/src/" -v "C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -P --name DockerizedWebApp1 --entrypoint tail dockerizedwebapp1:dev -f /dev/null
docker: Error response from daemon: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Drive has not been shared"}.
See 'docker run --help'.
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.10.6\build\Container.targets(198,5): error CTC1015: Docker command failed with exit code 125.
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.10.6\build\Container.targets(198,5): error CTC1015: docker: Error response from daemon: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Drive has not been shared"}.
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.10.6\build\Container.targets(198,5): error CTC1015: See 'docker run --help'.
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.10.6\build\Container.targets(198,5): error CTC1015: If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.
```

Needless to say '*docker run --help*' **did not help** at all (missing links/anchors in the Docker docs etc.).

Some additional info:

- Application is what VS2019 scaffolds **without any modifications**.
- Docker image is Linux (**which one I cannot tell**).
- Docker version is **19.03.5, build 633a0ea**

Since I am not familiar with Linux this error turns out to be like a "show-stopper" to me. Maybe Linux is not instructed to mount a drive? But which one? The message does not say it...

Maybe Windows has to share a drive, or map a folder to a drive that needs to be shared? The message does not say this either...

Here's a screenshot of the Docker dashboard:

[image]

And here's the Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["DockerizedWebApp1/DockerizedWebApp1.csproj", "DockerizedWebApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerizedWebApp1/DockerizedWebApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerizedWebApp1"
RUN dotnet build "DockerizedWebApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerizedWebApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerizedWebApp1.dl"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31):

The docker run command includes volumes from the C drive, e.g. `-v "C:\Users\admin\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw"`. For these to work, you need to include the C drive in your shared drives (check the box under settings -> resources -> file sharing). You can also move the files to be shared to the D drive which is already shared to the embedded VM, though that is likely not an option in this case. To know which drives to share, check the drives used in volume mounts in the run command.

In previous versions of docker for Windows, this would silently succeed and mount an empty folder into the container. So the error telling users to check the shared drives first is a nice improvement.

Comment: C: is my boot drive and the OS is installed on it. Do you really think it is a good practice to share such a sensitive information?

Comment: @AlexanderChristov the drive gets shared with the embedded VM which allows you to mount directories from that into the container. You can't say that you don't want to share the drive while also wanting to run commands that require access to directories on that drive. This is not a docker issue, this is an issue with the command you ask docker to run.

Comment: still "See 'docker run --help'." is quite useless. In fact it is somewhat harmful since leads to a pure waste of time, which, as you can see led to asking the question. anyway, thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderChristov that's a generic message for any command that fails, letting you know which subcommand help text may be relevant. Not sure how to adjust that to cover every possible error condition. The `500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Drive has not been shared"}` message that triggered the error is the useful part.

Comment: See this for where/when they generate that `--help` prompt: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/8e610b2b55bfd1bfa9436ab110d311f5e8a74dcb/cli/cobra.go#L40

Answer (score 18):

**Making drive C: available to Docker containers** from the Docker Dashboard **solved the problem**, look at the picture once again where it was not checked.

A couple of comments must be shared IMHO, however.

- The error message was not clear which drive needed to be shared (Linux supports *more than a single drive*, I guess)
- If without making drive C: available (or the bootable drive, the one where the OS resides) Docker *wouldn't be functional*, why after its installation it did not checked the drive itself? This is *just a click* (**!!**) in the Docker Dashboard, so it should be (relatively) easy.

A very simple explanation why this quite useless message was displayed may exist - Linux developers type a lot (CLI!) and being not very happy with this they do not type enough to give a meaningful diagnostics to their users.

Well, I do believe I am not right, but still **there must be an explanation why such a huge omission** appears in a final product.

Comment: Also, Docker is completely functional without having that drive checked, as long as you're not trying to bind-mount a directory from your local filesystem.  The only thing is that they want to follow the policies you set, and not set them for you.  (Imagine blindly running a script that mounts c:\windows into the container, and then being surprised when you find your SAM account hashes cracked... which was only permitted because they "helpfully" checked that box to share drive C and didn't tell you about it.)

Answer (score 7):

Add the Project under "File sharing" UI in docker:

[image: Add the Project under "File sharing" UI in docker]

Answer (score 1):

pull the long "docker run ... /dev/null"  command out of the output and run it by itself at a docker enabled command prompt.  Docker desktop should then prompt to allow sharing/network access.  You might want to restart the Docker Desktop app before doing so.