# Docker : Error response from daemon: user declined directory sharing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

While trying to run this command :

`docker-compose up`

I get this error :

`Error response from daemon: user declined directory sharing C:\Users\path_to_my_folder`

I am working on windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/59942110/596285

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error mounting a config file into the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755922/error-mounting-a-config-file-into-the-container)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/windows/#file-sharing) this problem is only relevant for Docker running on Windows in Hyper-V mode. Tagging it with "docker-windows-hyperv" or similar might be helpful.

Answer (score 87):

You have to add C:\Users\path_to_my_folder to Docker Filesharing.
Go to docker dashboard -> settings ->Resources -> FileSharing.
Add required folder and hit Apply & Restart.

Comment: Better yet, add whole C: drive

Comment: adding the whole **C: drive** might help right but not a great choice for security.

Answer (score 14):

Normally, Docker will [display a desktop notification](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/#shared-folders-on-demand) asking for your confirmation before sharing the folder.

[image: Docker sharing confirmation notification]

However, if notifications are disabled (for example, if you enabled Focus Assist), the confirmation box won't show and Docker will automatically decline the permission.

Answer (score 7):

Open Docker and follow this  -> settings ->Resources -> FileSharing. Add required folder and hit Apply & Restart

Answer (score 1):

If you have missed the notification or want to add any file or delete existing shared file path, go to Settings -> Resources -> File Sharing -> Use the +/- button -> Click Apply and Restart

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Answer from Kamran Huseyn worked for me perfectly on windows (this issue is not observed in my MacOS terminal).

Open Docker and follow this -> settings ->Resources -> FileSharing. Add required folder and hit Apply & Restart!

Comment: Just upvote and comment on the answer you like. Posting a new answer to say you like another answer is not useful.